# Google Android Publisher API inappproducts.insert permission error

Tags: node.js, react-native, in-app-billing, androidpublisher

I'm trying to have my server automatically create android in app payment products.

I'm currently using the `googleapis` npm package and a service account. The service account has the `View financial data`, `Manage orders and subscriptions`, and `View app information (read-only)` permissions. The service account can validate receipts perfectly fine, but upon trying to create a product using `google.androidpublisher("v3").inappproducts.insert()` it returns `Error: The caller does not have permission`

As far as I can tell the caller is the service account that has been given the permissions to do payment stuff. My one other option is to just give the account every possible permission and wait the day or so it takes for the permissions to propagate. In the meantime is there anything else I can do to give the service worker the needed permissions in order to be able to create in app products?